# How do I comment out sexps in elisp code?

Tags: emacs, elisp

What is the preferred way to comment out sexps in elisp code?  I have been wrapping my sexps in `(if nil ...)` so far.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`C-M-@ M-;` comments current sexp.

`C-M-@` stays for `mark-sexp` and `M-;` knows how to correctly comment out a region, taking the current mode into account. Commands to mark objects are described [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Marking-Objects.html).

Comment: `C-M-@` may also be bound to `C-M-SPC` which may be an easier to type and remember.

Answer (score 18):

Your `(if nil sexp)` construct will work just fine. I don't know if there is a standard equivalent in Emacs Lisp, though I suspect not. If you want to be more explicit about what you are doing, you could use something like the [comment macro in clojure](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/comment). Which is easily implemented as an Emacs Lisp macro.

```
(defmacro comment (&rest body)
  "Comment out one or more s-expressions."
  nil)
```

Then you could just write:

```
(comment 
  ...
  ; As many sexps as you want here...
  ...)
```

---

## EDIT:

Added `nil` to the end of the definition of the `comment` macro. As pointed out by [Marko Topolnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1103872/marko-topolnik), if you don't provide an implementation body, `defmacro` assumes that the docstring is actually the body. Explicitly putting a `nil` at the end works around this. Thanks for the catch Marko!

Comment: The macro is nice because you can have multiple sexps, whereas the if only works for a single sexp.  An obvious alternative would be (when nil ....)

Comment: Caveat: the macro only works for top-level forms. It expands to what the author apparently intended to be its doc string.

Answer (score 1):

semicolons -- ;;;

```
;;; insert into buffer
(defun thingy (foo)
  (interactive "stallman: ") ; prompt the user
  ; one semi-colon is also enough
  ;;;(insert (concat "deprecated")) ;;; this line will not execute
  (insert (concat "gnu-" foo)))
```

Comment: Thanks, but semicolons will comment out whole lines.  I was looking for a way to comment out individual sexps.

Comment: I rather doubt that you can comment out a sexp without using the language's comment mechanism. `(if nil sexp)` returns a value of nil, whereas a comment is ignored and has no value. As such, I would be a little wary of using the term "comment" to describe this, because that's not what it is.

Comment: yeah, I was fixating on "comment".... which are applied from the semicolon(s) to EOL